# is there any possibilities of opposite direction (invert) curve?

Tags: css

Please check below fiddle link, Is there any way to achieve opposite direction curve (invert),

[js fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/KxC9L/)

```
.roundCorner
{
width: 170px;
height: 20px;
padding: 2em;
border: 1px solid;
border-radius: 0 0 13em 13em / 0 0 3em 3em
}
```

**border-radius: 0 0 -13em -13em / 0 0 -3em -3em** is NOT working. Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to do a "reverse" border-radius. Which is a shame, because I've always kind of wanted a pure CSS layout that features a neat "integral-symbol-like" curve.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KxC9L/2/   after adding bakcground color for div, it's not working...please suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hacking around, [here's what I've got](http://jsfiddle.net/KxC9L/1/).

```
.roundCorner {
  width: 170px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 2em;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-bottom:0;
  position:relative;
}
.roundCorner:after {
  position:absolute;
  left:-1px;right:-1px;bottom:0;
  height:1.5em;
  border:1px solid black;
  border-bottom:0;
  border-radius: 13em 13em 0 0 / 3em 3em 0 0;
  content:'';
}
```

Basically it uses a psuedo-element to generate the bottom border of your element. It's hax, but it seems to work.

Comment: when I add background color for DIV along with body color, things broken?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KxC9L/2/   after adding bakcground color for div, it's not working...please suggest?

Comment: Add `background:white` to the `:after` element. If you have a different background colour on your main page, use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [CSS3 standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-radius) "Negative values are not allowed". So I think it very unlikely that any web browser will have added support for what you are trying to achieve.

You might have to achieve the look you want using border-image for custom border graphics. See [Understanding border-image](http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/) for some tips in this area.

Answer (score 0):

You could fake it by adding an element using the :before psuedo selector, and then applying a rounded border to that element. e.g. something along the lines of:

http://jsfiddle.net/gkghc/

```
.roundCorner
{
    width: 170px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-bottom: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.roundCorner:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 170px;
    height: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 13em 13em 0 0 / 3em 3em 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 30px;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KxC9L/2/   after adding bakcground color for div, it's not working...please suggest?